# how to get the value from previous page through reference or url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

this is my code for the page through which I want to Pass the Value

```
protected void UpdateDriver(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            HiddenField hid = (HiddenField)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("hdnID");
            int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(hid.Value);
            String Url = "UpdateDriver.aspx?" + "UserID=" + UserID;
            Response.Redirect(Url);
           // BalUsers.UpdateDriver();
         //   HiddenField hid = (HiddenField)gridview1.Cells[0].FindControl("hdnID");
          //  BalUsers
        }
```

So at the update driver page i WANT to get the UserID and pass it to my CommandText

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myconnection.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Ovms_New].[dbo].[tbl_driver] SET [lisenceNO] = ('@lisenceNO'),[liscenceType] = ('@liscenceType') WHERE (UserID = '@UserID')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconnection.Close();
          //  BalUsers.UpdateDriver(Convert.ToInt32(TextnewNo.Text), TextChangeType.Text);
        }
```

how to get that value and pass it to the query
thanks In Advance :)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/953114.aspx/1 hope this link helps u...

Answer (score 0):

you have to get it from the querystring

```
 string uID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["UserID"]);
```

Then plug it in your tsql statement

Comment: could you please help for a min using teamviewer? plz

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["UserID"];
```

or

```
Use Request.QueryString[0]
```

if thats the only parameter you're passing. Although won't follow this if I were you. This will break if you wanted to pass more parameters & change the order in the previous page.

Note: For the sake of completion, I would suggest you to encrypt the querystring for the sake of security.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: could you please help for a min using teamviewer? plz

Comment: its likely that something is null, on which line are you getting the object reference error?

Comment: Sir i dont think so i have security reasons... but i cant understand your point i am new to programming

Comment: ID=967 859 597 password= 7582

Comment: Sometimes, sensitive information shouldn't be passed using query params. For example www.somewebsite.com?bankaccountnum=893423824, you cannot do this because bank account number is sensitive and cannot show this to the end user http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33350/Encrypting-Query-Strings

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { i am getting it on that bracket

Comment: You have to declare myConnection like "SqlConnection myConnection..." and also cmd as "SqlCommand cmd..."